# R Shiny - nested Module not triggering events in server

Tags: r, shiny, module

I am trying to create an R Shiny app which requires nested modules. My code is functional when calling a single nested module but fails when I go one level deeper. The `ui` component is being created without issue, but the buttons etc. do not work within this module.

I have attached a simple example. Here, when you press the first button, it calls a module and creates a second button within a `wellPanel`. This is then repeated if this second button is pressed. However, I would expect that when I press the third button, I would get the string

> Third button Pressed

printed to screen.

Any suggestions?

```
library(shiny)

# Second Level Mod --------------------------------------------------------

second_mod_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- shiny::NS(id)
  fluidPage(
    wellPanel(
      actionButton(ns('addButton3'), '', icon = icon('plus'))
    )
  )
}

second_mod_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$addButton3, {
    print("Third button Pressed")
  })
}


# First Level Mod ---------------------------------------------------------------


first_mod_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- shiny::NS(id)
  shiny::uiOutput(ns("showButton"))
}

first_mod_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ns <- session$ns
  output$showButton <- renderUI({
    
    fluidPage(
      wellPanel(
        actionButton(ns('addButton2'), '', icon = icon('plus'))
      )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$addButton2, {
    i <- sprintf('%04d', input$addButton2)
    id <- sprintf('Button2%s', i)
    
    insertUI(
      selector = paste0('#', ns("addButton2")),
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = second_mod_ui(id)
    )
    
    callModule(second_mod_server, id)
  })
}

# Main App ----------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  actionButton('addButton1', '', icon = icon('plus'))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # If the Plus button has been pressed
  observeEvent(input$addButton1, {
    
    # Create a new id
    i <- sprintf('%04d', input$addButton1)
    id <- sprintf('Button1%s', i)
    
    # Insert the new UI
    insertUI(
      selector = '#addButton1',
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui = first_mod_ui(id)
    )
    
    # Call the server
    callModule(first_mod_server, id)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What is the usecase if I may ask? I have used Shiny quite a bit in the past, however I rarely needed modules and never nested ones. This doesn't mean its wrong. However I am curious about the reason:-).

Comment: Trying including `ns` in calling `second_mod_ui`, such as `ui = second_mod_ui(ns(id))`...

Comment: @Shamis. Basically the first will allow the user to add multiple analysis boxes (I.e. press add and a new box gets generated). This box will be the same for each and hence the use of a module. Within each box there is a requirement to add a dynamic number of variables,  each requiring the same inputs (I.e. name, type etc.) This can be thought of as a form. So each new variable is a new form to fill out. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Ben I believe this might have been it! It certainly works on my example shown. I really appreciate your help on this.