# Observe event within module nested in another module isn't recognizing input change

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I have a large wizard app that I'd like to break up by putting each of the hidden tabs within their own modules.

I've made the reprex below based off of [Hadleys wizard example](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#dynamic-wizard).

The layout is

```
ui
L outer_ui
  L inner_ui
server
L outer_server
  L inner_server
```

Things that do work:

- `inner_server` and `outer_server` communication: the `inner_server` can cause a page change on load
- `tabsetPanel` knows the tab in `inner_ui` exist: `page_21` button successfully switches to `page_1`

Thing that doesn't work:

- `inner_server` and `inner_ui` communication: the `observeEvent(input$page_12...` is not being triggered when the `page_12` button is pressed.

```
library(shiny)

inner_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(title = "page_1",
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("page_12"),
      label = "next")
  )
}

inner_server <- function(id, r, parent) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    r$page <- 2
    observeEvent(input$page_12, r$page <- 2)
  }
)}

outer_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
      # we name the set of tabs so we can call on the group later
      id = ns("wizard"),
      # this makes all the tabs except for the selected one hidden
      type = "hidden",
      
      # modularized the first page tab
      inner_ui("first_page"),
      
      # The other two tabs are identical to the Hadley example
      tabPanel(title = "page_2",
        h4("Only one page to go"),
        actionButton(inputId = ns("page_21"), label = "prev"),
        actionButton(inputId = ns("page_23"), label = "next")
      ),
      tabPanel(title = "page_3",
        h4("You're done!"),
        actionButton(inputId = ns("page_32"), label = "prev")
      )
    )
  )
}


outer_server <- function(id, r, parent) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(r$page, {
      updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "wizard", selected = paste0("page_", r$page))
    })
    inner_server("first_page", r = r, parent = session)
    observeEvent(input$page_21, r$page <- 1)
    observeEvent(input$page_23, r$page <- 3)
    observeEvent(input$page_32, r$page <- 2)
  }
  )
}

# Define the tabsetPanel module
ui <- navbarPage(
    title = NULL,
    tabPanel(title = "test Wizard",
      outer_ui("test_outer"))
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  r <- reactiveValues()
  outer_server("test_outer", r = r, parent = session)
}

# Run the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer from [Ben's comment on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65025544/r-shiny-nested-module-not-triggering-events-in-server).

Changing `inner_ui("first_page")` to `inner_ui(ns("first_page))` in the `inner_ui` function fixed the issue.